# Events in Backbone Relational: What are they for, what they do, and can the triggers be safely removed?

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-relational

I have been trying to decipher backbone.relational source code. I found that it fires a lot of its own events. I did a log on some of my models, and found that a lot of these events seem to fire off for no reason.

Big question is *which events should I listen to and which are internal events*

The events that Backbone.Relational seems to fire are:

- update:[attribute] seems to fire [Line 725, 941]
- relational:add This one seems to fire when .add() is called on a collection
- relational:remove This one seems to fire when .remove() is called on a collection [1651, 1003]
- relational:reset This one seems to have no rhyme or reason (why is being fired on sort!!!) [1664, 1675]
- relational:change:[attribute]: Have no idea what this does [1138]

Can someone explain what the purpose of each is and if some of the triggers can be removed from source

For comparison, Backbone's native events:

- "add" (model, collection, options) — when a model is added to a collection.
- "remove" (model, collection, options) — when a model is removed from a collection.
- "reset" (collection, options) — when the collection's entire contents have been replaced.
- "sort" (collection, options) — when the collection has been re-sorted.
- "change" (model, options) — when a model's attributes have changed.
- "change:[attribute]" (model, value, options) — when a specific attribute has been updated.
- "destroy" (model, collection, options) — when a model is destroyed.
- "request" (model, xhr, options) — when a model (or collection) has started a request to the server.
- "sync" (model, resp, options) — when a model (or collection) has been successfully synced with the server.
- "error" (model, xhr, options) — when a model's save call fails on the server.
- "invalid" (model, error, options) — when a model's validation fails on the client.
- "route:[name]" (params) — Fired by the router when a specific route is matched.
- "route" (router, route, params) — Fired by history (or router) when any route has been matched.
- "all" — this special event fires for any triggered event, passing the event name as the first argument.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The purposes of each event are quite clearly stated in the [Backbone.Relational readme](https://github.com/PaulUithol/Backbone-relational/blob/master/README.md):

- Bind new events to a `Backbone.RelationalModel` for:

  - addition to a `HasMany` relation (bind to `add:<key>`)
  - removal from a `HasMany` relation (bind to `remove:<key>`)
  - reset of a `HasMany` relation (bind to `reset:<key>`)
  - changes to the key itself on `HasMany` and `HasOne` relations (bind to `update:<key>`)

As for which events you should listen to: all of them, if you need to. That's why they're there, and documented.

As for which of them are used internally, the answer can be found in the [Backbone.Relational source](https://github.com/PaulUithol/Backbone-relational/blob/master/backbone-relational.js). If you search for `.bind` in the source file, you'll see that it listens internally to the following events:

- `relational:add`
- `relational:remove`
- `relational:change:key`
- `relational:reset`

So I doubt any of the event triggers can be "safely" removed from the source. Generally speaking I would say patching a library source is the wrong way to approach a problem.

You've posted a few questions related to Backbone.Relational events in the past few days. Maybe try to explain why are the events causing problems, and we'll look for a workaround?

Comment: Well I've basically spent a lot of time battling backbone events when saving back and forth from a server. The first time I load everything from the server everything is fine, but after a save things just start going haywire with events (starts adding/removing like crazy from my models). so I'm trying to get rid of as many extraneous events to make easier to debug. I'll try to document more of the problems I have when I get back to work Monday.